# Why does WPF have its own Color class instead of just using Drawing.Color?

Tags: wpf

Why does WPF have its own Color class instead of just using Drawing.Color?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know for certain, but I suspect it is for two reasons:

First, `Drawing.Color` does not support automatic conversion to and from floating point for ARGB values or color arithmetic, and both were necessary for WPF. They could have modified `Drawing.Color` to include it, but:

Second, `Drawing.Color` pollutes its namespace with static instances of itself for the various common colors. WPF wisely moves this to a separate static class called `Colors` to hold these instances.

I think it's likely as simple as that. Besides, Win.Forms and GDI+ will (hopefully) one day be deprecated and pruned. When that happens, there will be trouble if there's a dependency on the old .DLL. Better to just copy-pasta and enhance.

Comment: If WPF were invented today they would have just forwarded the Color class to System.DLL, but I guess that wasn't an option back then.